# Babel-jest does not transpile JSX in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, react-testing-library

Babel-jest does not transpile JSX / ES6 in `node_modules` folder when running tests
React components that does not use other components from `node_modules` pass all test correctly.

Try to add `transformIgnorePatterns` and rename to `babel.config.js` due to https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.2",
    "@babel/node": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "jest-dom": "3.1.3",
    .......
  },
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
    },
  },
};
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```

Comment: This kind of issue is usually quite complex due to dependencies so I suggest sharing the entire repository where people can get a copy of your working directory to test things out to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the link below was helped me.
Adding in `transformIgnorePatterns` my components from `node_modules` was enough, so `babel-jest` ignore all files instead of my components
[image from jestjs docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0K1i.png)
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization